# Uploading to Cloud Files or S3 skipping script host

Tags: php, amazon-s3, shared-hosting, bandwidth, rackspace

Is there a way to upload a file to Rackspace Cloud Files or Amazon S3 while skipping the script host as a temporary store before its moved to the cloud? I would like to minimize bandwidth to my shared hosting account.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Rackspace's service but [S3 lets you have users upload files directly with specially crafted forms](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html).  This means that the file never goes through your service.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the response. Now i need to know if Rackspace can do the same. i have an app that i want to use Rackspace & S3 as backup.